# Bootstrap Menu Item with Image and Text

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, menu, navigation

I am trying to add an image and text as a Bootstrap menu item.

I would like to be able to see the hover effect on this custom menu item in the same way as other items.

Also, my CSS code is pretty dirty; it uses `width:300px`, div inside links, etc. Can someone please suggest me how to do this better?

My code can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1290/).

```
<li>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <a href="/" style="display:block; width:300px; padding-left:20px;  color: black;" >
            <div class="pull-left">
                <img src="http://images.apple.com/iphone/home/images/productbrowser/icon_iphone_6.png" />                         
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left" style="margin-left:10px;">
                <span><strong>iPhone 6</strong></span>
                <br />
                <span>Bigger than bigger</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `<a>` tag above the clearfix and then just remove the inline `color:black;` on the `a` so that the hover color change works.

```
<li>
    <a href="/" style="display:block; width:300px; padding-left:20px;" >
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <img src="http://images.apple.com/iphone/home/images/productbrowser/icon_iphone_6.png" />                         
             </div>
             <div class="pull-left" style="margin-left:10px;">
                 <span><strong>iPhone 6</strong></span>
                 <br />
                 <span>Bigger than bigger</span>
             </div>        
         </div>
     </a>
 </li>
```

[**JSFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1320/)

In regards to css, firstly, I would not use inline styles - put the styles on the style sheet. You should preferably use `width: auto;` and use floats and padding to position the elements inside the menu item.